# How to store nested data in MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql

So I'm making a course table which stores course details, which will be displayed on my website. Now each course will have multiple videos/chapters. Eg: A course named stone age, might have 3 chapters pre historic, mediaeval, modern. I need to store link to these three videos under a single course which is "stone age". How do I do that?

- Stone Age

  - pre historic
  - mediaeval
  - modern
- course 2
  etc...

My course table has coursename, coursesubject, coursedescription, cprice, cid, cimg.
Do I need to make another table to store the media content for this course? Or can it be done using a single table?

Comment: 'Do I need to make another table to store the media content for this course' - Yes, and do read up on normalisation.

Comment: You *can* do it any way you like, you *should* create a normallised schema.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a column for the course, one for the chapter and finally one for the video.

```
CREATE TABLE course_videos (
   CourseName VARCHAR(25),
   Chapter VARCHAR(25),
   Video VARCHAR(50)
   );
```

I'm assuming that you're storing a URL for the video and not the video itself.
An entry might be:

```
INSERT INTO course_videos VALUES (
  'Stone Age' ,
   'pre historique'
   'name of the video.mp4'
   );
```

One simple table will handle the 2 levels of the heirarchy. For the given application I don't anticipate a large number of entries ( <1000) so storage space and optimization of performance are not concerns.

Comment: WHY do you suggest this approach?

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you for the question. One simple table will handle the 2 levels of the heirarchy. For the given application I don't anticipate a large number of entries so storage space and optimization of performance are not concerns.